# GraphQL integration with AWS problems

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, graphql

For school project, I have to create a developer tool. I am thinking in a library, tool or API to integrate GraphQL and AWS services seamless. What do you think? Have you dreamt with a tool that would make you work easier when using Graphql with AWS? What features would you like it to have?

Comment: I believe this question probably falls into the bucket of being "[not on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)" for StackOverflow.  Perhaps this question belongs elsewhere in the StackExchange family, or on a different site?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out AWS AppSync? https://aws.amazon.com/appsync/

Comment: Finally , we have created SuperGraphiQL, an upgraded version of GraphiQL: https://github.com/CSG4/super-graphiql